# Knapsack with quadratic constraint

Tags: np-complete, np-hard, decision-problem, knapsack-problems

Suppose I have a variant of the knapsack problem:

$$\max_{x} \sum_{i=1}^n v_ix_i$$

$$(\sum_{i=1}^n w_ix_i - W)^2 \leq k$$

for $v_i, w_i \in \mathbb{R}$, $x_i \in \{0,1\}$ and $k \in \mathbb{R}, k > 0$.

Is it known if the decision problem $\sum_{i=1}^n v_ix_i > V$ for some $V$ is NP-Complete?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is clearly in $\mathsf{NP}$. You can see that it is $\mathsf{NP}$-hard by a reduction from subset sum: given a set $X = \{ x_1, \dots, x_m \}$ of positive integers and another integer $T>0$, is there a subset $S$ of $X$ such that $\sum_{x \in S} x = T$?

To reduce to your version of subset sum, create $n=m$ items, where the $i$-th item has value $v_i = 1$ and weight $w_i=2x_i$, and set $W=2T$,  $k=1$, $V=0$. There is a solution to this "knapsack" instance if and only if there is a solution to the subset sum problem.

Comment: I see. Though I'm specifying $k > 0$, it sounds like you can make all $w$ and $W$'s integer and then choose $k < 1$. Seems like I need stronger conditions on $k$...

Comment: I slightly modified the reduction to ensure $k>0$.